# How to disable Navigation Icon when using Android Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-toolbar, android-jetpack

When you register a toolbar with navigation architecture it will create an arrow allowing you to pop up on the fragment you are on.

On a few base level fragments I don't want to have the Hamburger menu icon nor the arrow but a custom view object.

How would I disable the back button from view?

I have tried manually disabling but am having a hard time finding out how to manage it with Navigation arch.

```
val supportActionBar = activity?.actionBar
    if (supportActionBar != null) {
        supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false)
        supportActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(null)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after a good hour I hope that my pain and oversight really helps someone out. After Navigation Architecture forces you to load up a drawable into the navigation icon the only solution I came up with was to nullify it.

```
toolbar.navigationIcon = null
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this:

```
val actionBar = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar
actionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
```

Anyway, you should also keep in mind that you need to change navigation graph to set proper popUpTo destination or somehow disable system back button.